$G$ hamiltonian iff $H^2$ is hamiltonian
Let $G$ be a graph on the vertex set $V = \{v_0, \ldots, v_{n-1}\}$. Construct $H$ as the graph on vertex set $\{v_0, \ldots, v_{n-1}, u_0, \ldots, u_{n-1}, w_0, \ldots, w_{n-1}\}$ with
$$
E(H) = E(G) \cup \{v_iu_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{Z}_n} \cup \{u_iw_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{Z}_n}
$$
I want to prove that $G$ is hamiltonian if and only if $H^2$ is hamiltonian. Here $H^2$ is the graph obtained from $H$ by adding edges between all vertices of distance at most $2$. I have looked at some small examples, e.g. $G = K_3, G= C_4$ etc.. I have tried to do some degree considerations to maybe apply Ore's condition, without much luck. Any help would be appreciated:)

Is $H^2$ obtained from $H$ by adding new edges between every two vertices having distance two?

Yes! I should add that in the post

Let the Hamiltonian cycle in $G$ be $v_1 v_2 \dots v_{n} $. Then in $H^2$, note that $u_i \sim v_{i+1}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ and $u_n \sim v_1$, and that $w_i \sim v_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. Then $v_1 w_1 u_1 v_2 w_2 u_2 \dots v_n w_n u_n$ is the desired Hamiltonian cycle (draw a picture).
For the converse direction, let $V, W, U \subseteq V(G)$ be subsets of $V(G)$ consisting of all vertices with the labels $v,w$ and $u$ respectively (so that $\left|V\right| = \left|W\right|= \left|U\right| = n$). One needs to observe that:
Lemma 1: In $H^2$, $U$ and $W$ are independent sets. Moreover, the only edges between vertices in $U$ and vertices in $W$ are $\{u_i w_i \mid 1 \leq i \leq n\}$.
Proof: I'll leave this one to you.
Lemma 2: In $H^2$, $w_n$ only has two neighbors, which are $v_n$ and $u_n$.
Proof: In $H$, $w_n$'s only neighbor is $u_n$, whose only neighbor is $v_n$.
Now, say $H^2$ is Hamiltonian and consider $w_i$, which is in the Hamiltonian cycle. By Lemma 2, the vertices $u_i$, $w_i$ and $v_i$ must appear consecutively in $C$. This holds for each $1 \leq i \leq n$. Since by Lemma 1, since $U$ is an independent set, each $u_i$ must be sandwitched between a vertex in $V$ and a vertex in $W$. This forces the Hamiltonian cycle (reversing the cycle if needed) to be of the form $v_{i_i}w_{i_1}u_{i_1} \; \;  v_{i_i}w_{i_2}u_{i_2} \;\; \dots \;\;v_{i_i}w_{i_n}u_{i_n}$, where $i_k \in \{ 1, \dots, n \}$ are distinct indices. The `crossing over' edge between $u_{i_k}$ and $v_{i_{k+1}}$ indicate that $u_{i_k}$ and $v_{i_{k+1}}$ are of distance $2$ apart in $H$, and the only way this can happen is if $v_{i_k} \sim v_{i_{k+1}}$ in $G$. Repeating this, we get a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$.
